# Problem facing while getting JSON keys from an array of JSON's in hive

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have a Nested json and I want to extract array of values

```
{
  "Event": "Mohan",
  "Job ID": 1,
  "Submission Time": 18032203,
  "Stage Infos": [
    {
      "Stage ID": 2,
      "Stage Attempt ID": 0,
      "Stage Name": "Stage_name",
      "Number of Tasks": 1394
    },
    {
      "Stage ID": 3,
      "Stage Attempt ID": 0,
      "Stage Name": "Stage_name2",
      "Number of Tasks": 1894
    }
  ]
}
```

Query Im using:-

```
select  j.event
       ,j.job_id
       ,j.submission_time
       ,get_json_object  (spark_event,concat('$.Stage Infos[',e.i,'].Stage ID'))    as stage_id
       ,get_json_object  (spark_event,concat('$.Stage Infos[',e.i,'].Stage Attempt ID'))   as atmpt_id
       ,get_json_object  (spark_event,concat('$.Stage Infos[',e.i,'].Stage Name'))    as stage_name
       ,get_json_object  (spark_event,concat('$.Stage Infos[',e.i,'].Number of Tasks'))   as number_tasks
from    table_test t
        lateral view    json_tuple  (spark_event,'Event','Job ID','Submission Time') j as event,job_id,submission_time
        lateral view    posexplode  (split(get_json_object (spark_event,'$.Stage Infos[*].Stage ID'),'","')) e as i,x
```

When i'm running the above query Im getting the below output

```
    event job_id  submission_time stage_id  atmpt_id  stage_name  number_tasks
    Mohan 1 18032203 2 0 Stage_name  1394
```

But i want something like the one the showed below.

```
    event job_id  submission_time stage_id  atmpt_id  stage_name  number_tasks
    Mohan 1 18032203 2 0 Stage_name  1394
    Mohan 1 18032203 3 0 Stage_name2 1894
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the value passed to split function has worked for me. Please check once:

```
select  
j.event, 
j.job_id,
j.submission_time,
get_json_object  (spark_event,concat('$.Stage Infos[',e.i,'].Stage ID'))    as stage_id,
get_json_object  (spark_event,concat('$.Stage Infos[',e.i,'].Stage Attempt ID'))   as atmpt_id,
get_json_object  (spark_event,concat('$.Stage Infos[',e.i,'].Stage Name'))    as stage_name,
get_json_object  (spark_event,concat('$.Stage Infos[',e.i,'].Number of Tasks'))   as number_tasks from    json_example t
lateral view    json_tuple  (spark_event,'Event','Job ID','Submission Time') j as event,job_id,submission_time
lateral view    posexplode  (split(get_json_object (spark_event,'$.Stage Infos[*]'),'},')) e as i,x;

event   job_id  submission_time stage_id    atmpt_id    stage_name  number_tasks
Mohan   1   18032203    2   0   Stage_name  1394
Mohan   1   18032203    3   0   Stage_name2 1894
```